# Azure Not Adding Access Policy Without Authorized Application

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

When I try to add an access policy without an "authorized application" (see the following photo) :
[image: without authorized application]

And then i press add i'm sent back to the access policy page but there is no new access policy to save. If i select an authorized application, it works.

Is this a bug with azure possibly or am i misunderstanding something?

Thank You! :]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you must specify the authorized application unless the principal is the application itself.